# How to prevent inline-block divs from wrapping?

Tags: html, css, layout

> [**jsFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UnNbW/)

I want the `div`s to:

- Wrap their content.
- Stay in their originally associated line, essentially without wrapping.

Basically, the tables are stacking below each other, when they can't stay on screen. I would rather they become hidden off screen.

I've tried adding `overflow: hidden;` to the main layout style. I do not want to fix a width for each `div`. It needs to fit content in.

```css
.layout {
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}

.layoutbacking {
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout" style="background: #222222; width: 100%">
  <div>
    <div class="layout layoutbacking">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>header 1</th>
          <th>header 2</th>
          <th>header 3</th>
          <th>header 4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>data 1</td>
          <td>data 2</td>
          <td>data 3</td>
          <td>data 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>data 1</td>
          <td>data 2</td>
          <td>data 3</td>
          <td>data 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>data 1</td>
          <td>data 2</td>
          <td>data 3</td>
          <td>data 4</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="layout">
      <div class="layout layoutbacking">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>header 1</th>
            <th>header 2</th>
            <th>header 3</th>
            <th>header 4</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data 1</td>
            <td>data 2</td>
            <td>data 3</td>
            <td>data 4</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="layout layoutbacking">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>header 1</th>
            <th>header 2</th>
            <th>header 3</th>
            <th>header 4</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data 1</td>
            <td>data 2</td>
            <td>data 3</td>
            <td>data 4</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="layout layoutbacking">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>header 1</th>
          <th>header 2</th>
          <th>header 3</th>
          <th>header 4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>data 1</td>
          <td>data 2</td>
          <td>data 3</td>
          <td>data 4</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="layout layoutbacking">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>header 1</th>
          <th>header 2</th>
          <th>header 3</th>
          <th>header 4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>data 1</td>
          <td>data 2</td>
          <td>data 3</td>
          <td>data 4</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap;` to your `.layout` style declaration.

This will do exactly what you need: preventing the divs from wrapping.

Watch the

> [**jsFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UnNbW/3/)

or run the following snippet *full screen* and resize it:

```css
.layout {
       white-space : nowrap; /* this does the trick */
          overflow : hidden; /* this prevents the grey divs from overflowing */
    vertical-align : top;
     border-radius : 15px;
           display : inline-block;
}

.layoutbacking {
    border-radius : 15px;
       background : #CCCCCC;
          padding : 5px;
           margin : 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout" style="background: #222222; width: 100%">
    <div>
        <div class="layout layoutbacking">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>header 1</th>
                    <th>header 2</th>
                    <th>header 3</th>
                    <th>header 4</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>data 1</td>
                    <td>data 2</td>
                    <td>data 3</td>
                    <td>data 4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>data 1</td>
                    <td>data 2</td>
                    <td>data 3</td>
                    <td>data 4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>data 1</td>
                    <td>data 2</td>
                    <td>data 3</td>
                    <td>data 4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="layout">
            <div class="layout layoutbacking">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>header 1</th>
                        <th>header 2</th>
                        <th>header 3</th>
                        <th>header 4</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>data 1</td>
                        <td>data 2</td>
                        <td>data 3</td>
                        <td>data 4</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="layout layoutbacking">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>header 1</th>
                        <th>header 2</th>
                        <th>header 3</th>
                        <th>header 4</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>data 1</td>
                        <td>data 2</td>
                        <td>data 3</td>
                        <td>data 4</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="layout layoutbacking">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>header 1</th>
                    <th>header 2</th>
                    <th>header 3</th>
                    <th>header 4</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>data 1</td>
                    <td>data 2</td>
                    <td>data 3</td>
                    <td>data 4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="layout layoutbacking">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>header 1</th>
                    <th>header 2</th>
                    <th>header 3</th>
                    <th>header 4</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>data 1</td>
                    <td>data 2</td>
                    <td>data 3</td>
                    <td>data 4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will stop text wrapping, and keep it inline

```
.leftContent { float: left; }
.rightContent { overflow: hidden; }
```